# Command line interface to make a ogg mono from stereo

Tags: command-line, sound, ogg-vorbis

Is there a command-line interface I can use to make one or more ogg-music-files into mono?

Answer (score 5):

sox is a nice tool for all sorts of command line audio processing

```
sox your_inputfile.ogg your_outputfile.ogg remix -
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use it with `oggdec` and `oggenc`. In good old unix fashion, the decoding and encoding process is separated, so `oggenc` cannot take ogg as input. However, it is straightforward and easily combined in a shellscript if so desired.

```
oggdec myfile.ogg
oggenc --downmix myfile.wav -o myfile_mono.ogg
rm myfile.wav
```

If you wish to control the output quality, run oggenc with the -q flag with a value from -1 (very low) to 10 (very high)